# laravel nova 4 dependsOn not working in actions

Tags: laravel

I want to show two select boxes in actions in laravel nova 4. Based on first select box option, second select box should be shown or hidden. It works well with resource but for actions it does not work. Is there anyway to fix this?

```
Select::make('Action','status')->options(['1'=>'Approve','2'=>'Reject'])->displayUsingLabels()->rules('required'),
Select::make('Reason','detail_3')->options(['name'=>'name',
                                            'Reports'=>'Reports',
                                            'Blurred'=>'Blurred',
                                           ])->dependsOn('status', function(Select $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData)
                                           {
                                             if ($formData->status == '2') {
                                                 $field->show()->rules(['required']);
                                             }          
                                           })->hide(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As today you can that in actions too, only available on nova 4 [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGRzN.png)